# Selenuim driver.Navigate().back() breaks the HTML DOM when navigating back words and forwards

Tags: c#, selenium, navigation

The code below clicks on each button and then clicks on dynamic link produced by the button which takes me to next page however when test navigates back it fails to carry out the similar steps because of "Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up". I need to test links and move backwards and forwards during the process.

Code to click and navigate

```
public static int ClickNestedLink(int ID, IList<string>allNestedlinks,IWebDriver _driver,string Url)
    {            
        //Find the product brand and click on its brand and click on product link
        foreach (string BrandName in allNestedlinks)
        {

            IList<string> ProductBrandButtonList = new List<string>();                 

            //Find different brands
            foreach (IWebElement ProductBrandButton in _driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("productSet")))
            {
                IWebElement ProductParent = ProductBrandButton.FindElement(By.ClassName("product-parent"));
                String test = ProductParent.GetAttribute("data-product-id");
                ProductBrandButtonList.Add(test);
                //Find links for a brand  
                IList<string> LinksCollection = new List<string>();

                foreach (IWebElement ImageLink in ProductParent.FindElements(By.ClassName("brand_image")))
                {                        
                    String ImageLike2 = ImageLink.GetAttribute("src");
                    LinksCollection.Add(ImageLike2);
                    ImageLink.Click();
                    IWebElement productBrandClick = ProductParent.FindElement(By.ClassName("product-brand"));
                    String Test2 = productBrandClick.Text;
                    productBrandClick.Click();
                    _driver.Navigate().Back();
                    Task.Delay(20000).Wait();                                            }
            }                
        }
        return (ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Click` and `Back` actions are loading a new page with new elements making the previous references obsolete.
To overcome this issue, you need locate the elements in each loop:

```
// iterate the products
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    var products = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent"));
    if (i >= products.Count)
        break;

    // get the product for the iteration
    var product = products[i];

    // iterate the links
    for (int j = 0; ; j++) {
        var links = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent .brand_image"));
        var brands = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent .product-brand"));
        if (j >= links.Count)
            break;

        // get the link and brand for the iteration
        var link = links[j];
        var brand = brands[j];

        // click and navigate back
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is as close as I can get to click and navigate back nested links.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I have 3 containers and each container can have multiple brands and links are generated depending on brand name users click on. 
This is as close as I can get to click and navigate back nested links. It works well for first product set(first iteration) in array however after finishing iterating doesn’t repeat the same process instead it keeps clicking on same links in product set it has already been through. Any Help/advice will be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a timing issue. I would wait for the first element to be removed just after the click or navigate back: `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(links[0]));`

Comment: Thanks for putting effort once again, I tried putting exception but still couldn’t get it to work, as I have looked into it, I think the issue is with links loop which iterates 10 times in this example and brand loop which iterates 3 times, I need to find a way to delete elements from links array after every 3 brands iterations.

Comment: Is there a way to delete certain number of elements from link array from top order?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

public static int ClickNestedLink2(int ID, IList allNestedlinks, IWebDriver _driver, string Url)
        {

```
        var products = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent"));
        var productCount = products.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < productCount; i++)
        {
            var product = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent"))[i];
            var brandButtonsCount = product.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent .brand_image")).Count;

            for (int btnIdx = 0; btnIdx < brandButtonsCount; btnIdx++)
            {
                product = _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent"))[i];
                var brandButton = product.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent .brand_image"))[btnIdx];

                brandButton.Click();

                var brandNameAnchor = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".productSet .product-parent .product-brand"));
                brandNameAnchor.Click();

                _driver.Navigate().Back();

                OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
                wait.Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

            }
        }
        return (ID = 0);
    }        
}
```